# How to run a ROS service call in another thread with boost

Tags: ros, boost, thread, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
my node as a class which calls a service. During that service call it needs to get notified by a topic. The callback is set up respectively. The problem is that during the service call no messages are received. I suspect that the node is blocked by the service call and cannot handle any callback calls. They just pop up after the service call has terminated.

Below is a similar example of that node.

```
class MyClass {
    callService(){
       my_srv.call(request);  // blocking here!
    }
    callback(){
       // do something <-- is never called during service request
    }
}
int main.. {
  ros::ServiceClient my_srv = n.serviceClient<..>("..");
  MyClass my_class(my_srv);
  n.subscribe(my_topic, 100, &MyClass::callback, &my_class);
  my_class.callService();
}
```

When trying to put the service call in another boost thread compilation leads to the error (see below)

```
 my_srv.call(request);  // blocking here!
```

Changed to:

```
 boost::thread myThread = boost::thread(boost::bind(&ros::ServiceClient::call, &my_srv, request));
```

Error:

```
 »bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, ros::ServiceClient*, request&)«
```

Any hints? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200665/how-to-run-a-ros-service-call-in-another-thread-with-boost/) by [Sebastian Rockel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1966/sebastian-rockel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Sebastian,

a couple of points:

- Service calls are blocking. This is a deliberate design decision. IMO, services should in general only be used for things which return quickly. If you want to query a long-running service asynchronously, that's a sign that that service should better be implemented as an actionlib action. (... assuming you control the implementation of the service, that is.)
- Your topic callbacks aren't triggered because they only are triggered when your node enters `ros::spin()` or `ros::spinOnce()`. In roscpp, there are threads which handle topics asynchronously, but they only fill the subscriber queues. When you call `ros::spin()`, your thread goes through the messages in the subscriber queues one by one and calls the corresponding callbacks. This means that if you're only using `ros::spin()`, your code won't be multi-threaded.
- A good solution for your problem could be the [ros::AsyncSpinner](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#Multi-threaded_Spinning) class. It starts a user-defined number of threads which all call ros::spin(), so you don't have to call it yourself any more. The drawback (as with any multi-threaded solution) is of course that now you need to make sure that all resources are properly locked to prevent data races.

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2015-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sebastian Rockel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1966/sebastian-rockel/) on 2015-01-09**:
Hi Martin, Thanks!

- I understand the second point and regarding the first point I completely agree. Unfortunately it's not my package and it was designed by uos like this on purpose;-)
- ros::AsyncSpinner looks interesting. I'll have a look if I can solve the problem pragmatically with it.